# Can I get Aela the Huntress to use the bow I give her?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there any way I can get Aela to upgrade her bow?  I've managed to get her to use the armor and melee weapon I give her, although she does sit around the house in her underwear now and I need to take/give her something back to get her to redress.  She just keeps using the same standard bow she always did.

I didn't see anything I could take from her nor anything that I could 'buy' from her store.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Equipment AI bug (bows)](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Followers#Equipment_AI_bug_.28bows.29).

Experiment with different bows and arrows. I can get Jenassa to use a Glass bow and Glass arrows. If she runs out of arrows she reverts to her standard bow. Since I rarely have enough Glass arrows for her, I give her a large stack of Iron arrows.

Also keep in mind that the follower is oblivious to your Smithing upgrades. The follower only looks at the base damage of the equipment to decide which is better.

Comment: Actually one bug that I noticed is that she always has 1 glass arrow and when I check corpses I find glass arrows (ala unlimited).  I'll play with it some, i've tried ebony, dwarven and imperial bows but she just loves that hunting bow.  I'll try stocking with lots of iron arrows.

Comment: Try different bow types. Glass bow works for me, but she may not equip Ebony or Daedric. Try Ebony bow + Iron arrows to be sure. If it doesn't work you may have to use an upgraded Glass bow. ps: Yeah, I did have that "infinite" glass arrow glitch on Lydia, very handy :) But with my Jenassa it doesn't work, she'll run out of arrows. Not sure how to reproduce it. She would be OP though so I don't miss it too much.

Comment: In addition to Smithing upgrades, followers seem to ignore Enchantments too. So, a legendary ebony bow with fire damage looks like a mundane, unimproved ebony bow.